# Google Sheets Percentages

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, percentage

I am trying to work out what 4% of a total would be in Google Sheets.

So:

- Column R is the total I need 4% of
- Column T holds the percentage amount I need (4)
- Column S shows what 4% is of column R

How do I do this please? So for example, someone is paid £12, this is inputted into column R, I need Column S to show what 4% is of £12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

logic is:

```
(a whole number multiplied by percentage) is subtracted from the whole number
```

formula is:

```
=R2-R2*4%
```

[image]

---

if you want the value of 4% then:

```
=R2*4%
```

[image]

---

reference can be done like:

```
=R2*T1%
```

[image]

---

and if you want to drag it down use:

```
=R2*T$1%
```

---

if you want to use ArrayFormula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(R2:R="";;R2:R*T1%))
```

---

if you want it shorter use:

```
=INDEX(IF(R2:R="";;R2:R*T1%))
```

---

if `T1` already has percentage value then use:

```
=INDEX(IF(R2:R="",,R2:R*T1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you need something like that:

`S1`  `=T1*R1`

then you can drag the formula down to all the cells, or copy the formula (paste formula) or create an array formula to apply this operation to all the desired cells.

[image: example]